# Ef 6.1 code first migration decimal? to decimal

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

everyone I'm using ef 6.1 code first with the automatic migration enabled. 
If, after you have created the db change a property to decimal? in decimal. Qunado tries to update the db I get the following error: 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll .... The column is not nullable. UPDATE fails.

How can I fix all automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there are already null values in your database. So there is a conflict between the not null restriction and the data.

Run the

> add-migration

command in the nuget console to add a migration.

Use that migration to fill the future non nullable field with a value and then mark the field non nullable.

The migration will not be generated automatically, but depending on your setup, it will be automatically deployed/migrated.

A nice article about automatic migrations can be found here: http://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/

Comment: Yes, but I have enabled automatic migration:Configuration():
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
} How should I do?

Comment: As far as I know they work well together. Do you receive any error's when trying to add the migration?

Comment: I wish I could update the db automatically without me from this type of error

Comment: Normally it is possible. But in this case the types are incompatible so you need some kind of transformation. The current `NULL` values will not default to `0` because it is a different type. There might be A slight chance that it will be possible with the fluent API. You'll need to set the SQL's `Default value or Binding`. But I can't help you with that.